# Select elements of array using array of integers

Tags: arrays, perl, subset

Is it possible to select specific elements of an array using an array of integers (indexes)? I know that this can be done easily with a loop, but I was hoping for a one-line solution.

Example:

```
@arr = qw(a b c d e f);
@arr2 = qw( 0 2 4);
```

Rather than:

```
@arr3 = @arr[0,2,4];
@arr3 = @arr[@arr2]; #won't work as @arr2 returns number of elements
@arr3 = @arr[join(',', @arr2)] #won't work as join returns a string
```

Comment: "`1@arr3 = @arr[@arr2]; #won't work as @arr2 returns number of elements`" - You're wrong there :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually already had the correct answer, but apparently never tried it. It's called an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices), and since a list of subscripts is expected, the array is evaluated in list context. Evaluating the array in scalar context returns the number of elements it contains, as you mentioned.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @arr1 = qw(a b c d e f);
my @arr2 = qw(0 2 4);
my @arr3 = @arr1[@arr2];

dd(\@arr3);
```

Output:

```
["a", "c", "e"]
```